# c# get element from HTML

Tags: c#, html, winforms

How can I get text from HTML code like this:

```
<tr class="tabelaZbiorczaAltRow"><td nowrap="">
<a href='javascript:danePobierzPelnyRaport("890002604","DaneRaportPrawnaPubl", 0);'>890002604</a>
</td><td nowrap="">P</td>
<td>GAZA  A.A.GĄSIEWICZ  SPÓŁKA JAWNA</td>
<td nowrap="">DOLNOŚLĄSKIE</td>
<td nowrap="">kłodzki</td>
<td nowrap="">Duszniki-Zdrój</td>
<td nowrap="">57-340</td>
<td nowrap="">Duszniki-Zdrój</td>
<td nowrap="">ul. Willowa 1</td>
<td nowrap="">----------</td>
</tr>
```

I need all texts in td nowrap tags I have to distinguish each of them.

Comment: What does this have to do with c#?

Comment: Use something like the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate any effort in solving this.  There are numerous questions out there about reading text out of HTML in C#.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do? Is this a string you are pulling into a c# application that you need to parse? Are you looking to read this html from javascript within the page?

Comment: All texts in td nowrap are returned by website. Ineed to reed them and write to data base.

Comment: WG97 do what Steve suggested.

Comment: Your comment isn't very useful. You say c# and winforms in your tags then talk about a website returning html. What EXACTLY is your setup.

Comment: Steve I say also html in tags if you can't see

Comment: Hi, while other have pointed you in the right direction with [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). . I will focus on the way you ask things. [tour], [ask], [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @WG97 When people ask for more information or to clarify existing information, simply repeating what you said in the question or directing us to read the question is generally unhelpful and not likely to get your question answered.

Answer (score -1):

It may help you

```
public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```